# スワイプで出てくるサブメニューのライブラリはありますか？

Tags: jquery

スマートフォンのアプリでよくある、スワイプで出てくるサブメニューのjQueryライブラリはありますか？

[image: 参考]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js

jQueryベースではないですが、こういうものではいかがでしょうか？